How to Integrate React GA4 and Firebase Analytics in the Same Project?
I’m working on a React project where I need to use both Google Analytics 4 (GA4) through react-ga4 and Firebase Analytics, for two different google analytics accounts. The issue I’m facing is that the data sent via react-ga4 does not appear in my Firebase Analytics dashboard.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
import ReactGA from 'react-ga4';
ReactGA.initialize('GA_TRACKING_ID_2');
ReactGA.send('pageview');

Set up Firebase Analytics using Firebase SDK:
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
  authDomain: "YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN",
  projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET",
  messagingSenderId: "YOUR_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID",
  appId: "YOUR_APP_ID",
  measurementId: "G-MEASUREMENT_ID_1"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

I’ve confirmed that Firebase Analytics works and captures events as expected.
The problem:
While Firebase events appear correctly in the Firebase Analytics dashboard, events sent through react-ga4 do not show up in the Firebase Analytics dashboard.
I expected that both GA4 and Firebase would report events to the same dashboard, but it seems like they aren't sharing data.
My questions:

Is it possible to use react-ga4 and Firebase Analytics together in the same project? If so, how can I ensure that both services log events correctly?

Could there be any configuration conflicts between GA4 and Firebase Analytics that I’m missing?


Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!
